# Android Webview - javascript screen dimensions vs actual screen dimensions

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a very simple Activity with the following layout...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `Activity` itself is set for full screen (no title bar and no Android notification bar) and forced to landscape.

So...on my HTC Desire, the `WebView` in theory is occupying 800x480 (wxh) pixels. All good so far, it DOES fill the screen totally.

The confusion I have is that the `WebView` loads an HTML document from a server which uses a javascript function to get the screen width and height...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function getDims() {
        var screenW = screen.width;
        var screenH = screen.height;
        return "size=" + screenW + "x" + screenH;
    };
-->
</script>
```

...the problem is that `screenW` is 527 and `screenH` is 320 and I don't understand why.

Looking at a height of 320, it's exactly two-thirds of 480 so I then looked at what two-thirds of 800 is (~533). So it seems both `screen.width` and `screen.height` in the javascript are reporting two-thirds of actual pixels available.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For website you can control the screen size in android using a meta tag in your site.

There are three settings for the "screen" size low-dpi, medium-dpi and high-dpi.

So the device is automatically scaling your website (it assumes medium-dpi if you didn't set anything)

In javascript you don't get the exact pixel size of the device, you get more like the device is somewhere in that area...

A good explanation for this can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

Comment: Thank you - I'm a javascript and web-app rookie. I hadn't found that web-app guide, it looks really useful. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that document has explained a great deal. Thanks again.