# Get actual height of mobile device with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get the actual device height of an Android device in portrait mode in javascript/jQuery? I'm using a Galaxy S Advance with Android version 2.3.6

I've tried the following options so far:

```
screen.height
window.innerHeight
document.documentElement.clientHeight

$(window).height()
```

All of those options return 450px, which is not the device height. The pixel ratio is 1.5, so 450*1.5 = 675. My actual device height should be 800, so I'm missing the 125 pixels of the address bar.

Is there a way to calculate the height of the actual screen?

I know this will not be 800, but 800/1.5, which is 533.

Thanks in advance :)

PS. Sorry if there was any confusion, but the question is about a website I have to test on Android, not a Java application.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Metadata). This question is a possible duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628860/android-webview-javascript-screen-dimensions-vs-actual-screen-dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the height value in pixels you can use getSize:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int height = size.y;
```

If you're not in an Activity you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Before getSize was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the getHeight methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I actually meant the device height via Javascript for the webbrowser, not an application. I've edited my start post so it will be more clear.