# Run an android service when the application is closed

Tags: android, android-service

Can anyone tell me where to search for the following?
I'm trying to create an application that allows the user to schedule an SMS to be sent at a specific time.
I can do this when the application is open and running but I want my application to work even if it is not running, using a service for example.
Can anyone tell my where can I find any resource for doing that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Webview - javascript screen dimensions vs actual screen dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628860/android-webview-javascript-screen-dimensions-vs-actual-screen-dimensions)

Comment: For common informations about services just check the android developer guide http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html as well as http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html. Hope this helps for the start.

Answer (score 2):

U will need to use WakefulBroadcastReceiver to achieve this see this example

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast

Comment: Yes, this is probably what you want. The official documentation for WakefulBroadcastReceiver can be found here. There is some good examples there. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html